# MSMQ read fails during high load in .Net

Tags: msmq

I'm sending and receiving message on an msmq. It works fine under low load, but as soon as I pump it up to 100 messages a minute, after a few minutes I get when I try to read off the queue:

```
System.Exception: Stream was not readable.
    at System.IO.BinaryReader..ctor(Stream input, Encoding encoding)
    at System.IO.BinaryReader..ctor(Stream input)
```

Any idea on how I go about resolving an issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

100 messages per minute is trivial for MSMQ... are you 100% sure the exception isn't coming from somewhere else? More code would have helped. How exactly are you reading from the queue? Are you writing to it from the same process or thread?

Comment: The stacktrace seems to suggest the following line where QMsg is of type Message.  <br>New BinaryReader(QMsg.BodyStream).  <br>Yes, I believe I'm reading on the same thread.

Comment: If you could post your code here we could review it for you? I have used MSMQ in systems where we send several hundred of msgs/sec through it!